# Ctrl-] matching single word in custom tags

Tags: tags, help-system

When using vim's help I can jump to multi-word tags, but when creating my own tags Ctrl-] tries to match individual words. Consider the following example:

**file.txt**

> |a-tag|
>   *a-tag*

When pressing Ctrl-[ over "a" it tries to match "a" and not "a-tag". 
Similarly, if the cursor is on top of "tag" vim searches for "tag" only. 
When visually selecting "a-tag" it works.

The tags file is the following:

**tags**

> a-tag    file.txt    /*a-tag*

#### How do I change Ctrl-] behavior to search for the whole WORD inside |a-tag|?

Comment: Have you tried setting the filetype to help?

Comment: Check your `iskeyword` setting. Vims help file use a custom `iskeyword` setting, as can be seen by `:verbose set isk? `